# How the conflict between these two verse of Quran can be solved?

Tags: history, tafseer, jihad, war

First verse says:

> And whoever turns his back to them on such a day, unless swerving [as
>   a strategy] for war or joining [another] company, has certainly
>   returned with anger [upon him] from Allah, **and his refuge is Hell** -
>   and wretched is the destination. [8:16](http://tanzil.net/#8:16)

Second is:

> Allah has already given you victory in many regions and [even] on the
>   day of Hunayn, when your great number pleased you, but it did not
>   avail you at all, and the earth was confining for you with its
>   vastness; **then you turned back, fleeing**. [9:25](http://tanzil.net/#9:25)

This verse is clearly saying all or some of Muslims with prophet fled from war and so they will be in Hell.

Does this means that who were at prophet army prophet are in Hell ?

They were Muslims and by combining these two verse it means Muslims are in hell! Is not it conflict in Quran?

How this can be solved ?

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: @AlUmmat simple: one verse say: who fled war is in Hell. second says you (Muslims) fled from Hunayn war. result: Muslims are in hell. are Muslims in hell really? if not how you explain this?

Comment: the verse dd not say that they were in hell.

Comment: the first verse says who fled war will go Hell. second says you (Muslims) fled war. by combining two verse result is: you (Muslims) will go hell. OK? X will go hell. you are X. so => you will go hell. ok? logical

Comment: they did not totally flee they gone back to the war, and they won.  Read the Ayah after that.

Comment: the next ayah is talking about "prophet and believers" that I think are who resisted and did not flee because I do not think prophet fled any war. assume prophet himself flee! who won? who did flee. or prophet and who remained with him? also the next verse does not say they gone back. even if they gone back anyway they have included in the first verse (who flee will go hell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The holy Quran answers your question itself:

By having accepted the first verse ([8:16](http://tanzil.net/#8:16)) and the fact that:

**1)** Whoever turns his back to the disbelievers and escapes from them in a war, will go to the hell.

Let’s have a look at the second verse ([9:25](http://tanzil.net/#9:25)) and its following two verses([9:26](http://tanzil.net/#9:26) and [9:27](http://tanzil.net/#9:27))

> لَقَدْ نَصَرَ‌كُمُ اللَّـهُ فِي مَوَاطِنَ كَثِيرَ‌ةٍ ۙ وَيَوْمَ حُنَيْنٍ ۙ إِذْ أَعْجَبَتْكُمْ كَثْرَ‌تُكُمْ فَلَمْ تُغْنِ عَنكُمْ شَيْئًا وَضَاقَتْ عَلَيْكُمُ الْأَرْ‌ضُ بِمَا رَ‌حُبَتْ **ثُمَّ وَلَّيْتُم مُّدْبِرِ‌ينَ**
>
> Allah has already given you victory in many regions and [even] on the day of Hunayn, when your great number pleased you, but it did not avail you at all, and the earth was confining for you with its vastness; **then you turned back, fleeing**. [9:25]
>
> ثُمَّ أَنزَلَ اللَّـهُ سَكِينَتَهُ عَلَىٰ رَ‌سُولِهِ وَعَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ وَأَنزَلَ جُنُودًا لَّمْ تَرَ‌وْهَا وَعَذَّبَ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُ‌وا ۚ وَذَٰلِكَ جَزَاءُ الْكَافِرِ‌ينَ
>
> Then Allah sent down His tranquility upon His Messenger and upon the believers and sent down soldiers angels whom you did not see and punished those who disbelieved. And that is the recompense of the disbelievers. [9:26]
>
> **ثُمَّ يَتُوبُ اللَّـهُ مِن بَعْدِ ذَٰلِكَ عَلَىٰ مَن يَشَاءُ ۗ** وَاللَّـهُ غَفُورٌ‌ رَّ‌حِيمٌ
>
> **Then Allah will accept repentance after that for whom He wills**; and Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. [9:27]

**2)** And we believe that whoever Allah accepts repentance from him won't go to the hell (at least for that sin).

So according to the verse 9:27 we should change our first hypothesis to the following one:

**(1)** + **(2)** = **Whoever turns his back to the disbelievers and escapes from them in a war, will go to the hell, except those ones Allah has accepted their repentance.**

Is there any conflict yet in our holy Quran?

Comment: thanks. no now there is no conflict. yes who God forgive will not go Hell and who God not forgive will go.

Answer (score 3):

What really happened is that the Muslim army included big number of الطلقاء, people who the Prophet forgave when he conquered Mekkah. They were either new muslims with no deep belief in Allah, or hypocrites who were just waiting for a chance to fail muslims.

When the arrows of Hawazen army came like falling rains, most of those الطلقاء flew away either because they became scared because they have weak faith, or because they were hypocrites and found it a good chance to fail muslims. That fled away made big confusion in the Muslim Army, and the "original" Muslims were confused what to do, some thought it was a general retreat and fled away, some went back to return those who fled into the battle field before the wrath of Allah be cast upon them (as comes in the [Aya](http://quran.com/8/16) you mentioned). The Prophet (pbuh), who wasn't in an easy to find place, moved to the right of the army and ordered Abbas to retreat the muslims towards the Prophet, and so he did, and muslims did so (with some details).

This is a quotation by Al-Abbas that describes some of these details, sorry I can't translate right now due to the lack of time:

> روى مسلم من حديث العباس ـ رضي الله عنه ـ قال شهدت مع رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ يوم حنين فلزمت أنا وأبو سفيان بن الحارث بن عبد المطلب رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ فلم نفارقه ، ورسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ على بغلة له بيضاء أهداها له فروة بن نفاثة الجذامي ، فلما التقى المسلمون والكفار ولى المسلمون مدبرين ، فطفق رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ يركض بغلته قبل الكفار ، قال عباس : وأنا آخذ بلجام بغلة رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ أكفها إرادة أن لا تسرع ، وأبو سفيان آخذ بركاب رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ، فقال رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ : " أي عباس ناد أصحاب السمرة " فقال عباس ( وكان رجلا صيتا ) فقلت بأعلى صوتي : أين أصحاب السمرة ؟ قال : فوالله لكأن عطفتهم حين سمعوا صوتي عطفة البقر على أولادها ، فقالوا : يا لبيك يا لبيك ، قال : فاقتتلوا والكفار ، والدعوة في الأنصار يقولون : يا معشر الأنصار يا معشر الأنصار . قال : ثم قصرت الدعوة على بني الحارث بن الخزرج ، فقالوا : يا بني الحارث بن الخزرج يا بني الحارث بن الخزرج ، فنظر رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ وهو على بغلته كالمتطاول عليها إلى قتالهم [ ص: 227 ] فقال رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ هذا حين حمي الوطيس قال : ثم أخذ رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ حصيات فرمى بهن وجوه الكفار ، ثم قال : " انهزموا ورب محمد " قال : فذهبت أنظر فإذا القتال على هيئته فيما أرى ، قال : فوالله ما هو إلا أن رماهم بحصياته فما زلت أرى حدهم كليلا وأمرهم مدبرا
>
> [Source](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=65&ID=516&idfrom=1540&idto=1548&bookid=65&startno=4)

The same Source page includes a quotation of Imam Al Nawawi (may Allah be peaceful to him) that explains that "The fled was not far away, and they returned so soon".

Source: Tafseer Al Manar. These pages: [1](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=65&ID=516&idfrom=1540&idto=1548&bookid=65&startno=4) and [2](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=65&ID=1548).

Comment: Good answer, but what does الطلقاء means? Is it the same thing as [Munafiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munafiq)?

Comment: @yasar11732: No, Munafiq means hypocrites, one who pretends to be muslim and he isn't. الطلقاء are people who the Prophet forgave when he conquered Mekkah, they're called so because he said to them "اذهبوا فأنتم الطلقاء" Arabic for "Go, you are free" or "Go, you are the freed ones" hence the name طلقاء the freed people (not precise translation).

Comment: -1 , As I (and many others) don't understand Arabic the quotation by Al-Abbas doesn't make any sense. I'll remove it after the translation

Comment: thanks for good answer. but I think this does not still answer the question. question is if those who fled (even of backed again) will go to hell or not? how you explain conflict of 2 verse. your answer is only explaining what happened. please read answer carefully again. details of what happened is not needed to answer this question. also I doubt all who fled were from Tulaqa. some famous non Tulaqa sahaba were among them.